# fixed header - with navigation for e-com site

Tags: navigation, e-commerce, conversion, header

I have an e-commerce site. I believe it makes sense to have a fixed header when a user scrolls down. This will show the items in the cart, and will also show the visitor when they have added a new item to the cart, as its done client side.

I also have the top nav fixed to the header as well. I was wondering if this is too much, and takes away from the screen size, particularly on low resolution screens. Thus taking away from the experience of the site.

Has anyone had any experience with conversions on keeping a fixed nav in the header. Presumably the intention is to help the visitor navigate, but do they really use it anyway? And is it that big a deal to have to scroll to the top?

Comment: Could you possible provide a quick mockup of what it looks like? Just so I can get an idea of how much content we are looking at here.

Comment: the  nav bar has a height of about 45px, and the header does too. Giving it a total of 90px in height. Taking away nearly 100px of screen viewing.

Comment: 100px is way too much to much screen. Transition to a streamlined header on scroll with only the essential functions.

Answer (score 1):

Try to post a mockup, I'm running an eCommerce startup that's like Amazon + Pinterest and we did focus study groups finding a "Back to Top" was more effective in saving space via Mobile and seems it was preferred even on Desktop in comparison of a fixed header (ours is nearly 200px).

It totally depends on the usage of this header and I tend to agree of a fixed header but I thought wrong apparently to my test results. I'll try to summarize a case study and post later to share the statistics.

Answer (score 0):

if the site have more content to scroll to down , i prefer fixed header , but in the other side , specially in small screens it's a pain , i had this experience in one of my project , after few months later , client asked me to remove it , he said it's bad UX :) but that site not too much content that's mean not too much scrolling !